# Ubuntu 19.10 completely lost the GUI

Tags: gnome, gui

I was troubleshooting another issue and ended up removing the gnome settings manager using `sudo apt-get remove gnome-settings-manager` and rebooted.

After rebooting I am unable to access my Ubuntu GUI. I can only see a black screen with disk information. I can get into a terminal with ctrl-alt-F7. I tried reinstalling the setting manager, but I still cant see my GUI. How can I restore my GUI?

Comment: It might help if you post a screenshot of what you're seeing.

Comment: If there was a way to install/enable the GUI/Gnome system from scratch using the terminal I think that would be the easiest answer

Comment: You might try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to reconfigure the display manager after reinstalling ubuntu desktop, as described by @oscar1919's answer.

Comment: Also, when you making substantive changes like this, try out Timeshift to make a snapshot of your system you can restore to if you need. https://itsfoss.com/backup-restore-linux-timeshift/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember having the same problem.  I think I solved it by:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
Maybe also:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop`

Other suggested command after reinstalling the desktop (courtesy of @Ken Kinder by comment), to reconfigure the display manager:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: will this delete my personal data

Comment: this fixed it for me! Thank you Oscar